# Link takes double click to activate- how to make it only one? Angular 5

Tags: html, angular

I'm building an app in Angular 5 and have a navigation component that will display various tabs/links. When the link is active (currently being viewed) the tab will have a border around it and look like it is the front of a file folder.

The problem is, I only need to click once in order to make the link appear active, but have to click the tab/text twice in order to get it to actually load the page. Why is that, and how can I get it to load completely after one click? Does this happen because I have two click events activated on one link?

**My tabs in html:**

```
 <div *ngIf="authService.current_route == '/' ">
        <a [routerLink]="['']" data-toggle="tab">
            <li [class.active-link]="selectedTab === 0" (click)="changeroute()" (click)="selectTab(0)" >Site List</li>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/sites/map']" data-toggle="tab">
            <li [class.active-link]="selectedTab === 1" (click)="changeroute()" (click)="selectTab(1)" >All Sites Map</li>
        </a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/user-access']" data-toggle="tab">
            <li [class.active-link]="selectedTab === 2" (click)="changeroute()" (click)="selectTab(2)" >User Access</li>
        </a>
  </div>
```

In my component:

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
   deciding_route: any;
   selectedTab = 0;
   current_site;
   local_route
   current_site_id

selectTab(tabId: number) {
    this.selectedTab = tabId;
 }
constructor(public authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

changeroute() {
   this.authService.current_route = this.router.url;
   this.authService.route_with_id = this.authService.current_route
}

}
```

Thanks so much!! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Have you tried removing one of the click events to see if that changes its behavior? (I've never seen/tried defining multiple events of the same type on one element.) EDIT: OK ... I just tried this and it *does* seem to work to have multiple events of the same type on an element.

Comment: You could try writing it with one click event something like this: `(click)="changeroute();selectTab(0);"`

Comment: You could try to turn on route tracing to see if that provides any insight into why the routing isn't working on a single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might seem to be related with the fact that the click will trigger before the router actually change the route, then, calling your method `changeroute();` doesn't change anything because the route is still the same at this time; however, when you click the second time, the route have already been changed, after the first click handler, so it changes according to the expected route.

A way out is to transfer the `changeroute()` method to a route change listener:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.changes.subscribe((val) => { this.changeroute(); })
}
```

> You could also move the click handler upwards, i.e, move to an element which would be parent of the `routerLink` so that your click would happen after the click on the link, it might work as well.

#### Further explanation

Consider the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: `
    <div (click)="onClick1()">
      <button (click)="onClick2()">Click</button>
    </div>`,
})
export class TestComponent  {
  onClick1(){
    console.log('click 1')
  }  
  onClick2(){
    console.log('click 2')
  }
}
```

If the button gets clicked, it is going to display the console like bellow:

```
click 2    
click 1
```

It implies the propagation starts on the child (tip) to parents until reach the root node (provided that your would have listener for all parents until the root).

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an error in the component I was navigating from but no error in the console because navigate is a promise.

After consuming the promise I found the issue it the error written to the console.

```
const nav = this.router.navigate(['myapp/dashboard']);

nav
 .then((v) => {
    console.debug('to dashboard', v);
 })
 .catch((e) => {
    console.error('to dashboard', e);
 });
```